# Changing a copy of an Array changes the Array itself?

Tags: arrays, queue

This should be a really simple task but I keep failing at it.
I have a String Array called "root" which I want to keep untouched.
shift() instead uses a copy of root which I called "temproot".
temproot is set equal to root before the method is called.
However, printing out root reveals that it changes every time shift() is called, although the method itself doesn't touch root at all.

```
static String[] shift() {
    String temp = temproot[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < temproot.length - 1; i++) {
        temproot[i] = temproot[i + 1];
    }
    temproot[temproot.length - 1] = temp;
    return temproot;
}
```

As additional info, here's the method that changes root. It receives a variable number of Integers and stores them as Strings in root.

```
static void change(int... intervals) {
    int[] in = intervals;
    String[] ints = new String[in.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
        ints[i] = Integer.toString(in[i]);
    }
    root = ints;
    temproot = root;
}
```

This is called only once, and after that only shift() is called. In the main method, it looks like this:

```
protected static String[] root;
protected static String[] temproot;

change(4, 3, 5);    // Major
    name("x", root); name("x/3", shift()); name("x/5", shift());
```

As you may notice, the program is designed to automatically name chords based on their interval "mask". For example, Major chords are made up of a major 3rd (4 semitones) followed by a minor 3rd (3 semitones), and then it's 5 semitones to the next root (because there are 12 notes in an octave). In first inversion, the 3rd is at the bottom, and in second inversion, the 5th is. In order to replace "x" with the same note for each inversion, name() uses "root". Therefore, it's essential that root stays the same after every shift.

I don't see how shift() alone can change root. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you did is not actually a copy. `temproot = root;` will not create a copy of root. That only works with primitive data types! An array is a reference type. You are just setting a reference to root.
Have a look here how to make an actual copy: https://www.baeldung.com/java-array-copy